# Make dpkg to know compiled programs : git

Tags: apt

I installed git by compiling from source. When I tried to install atom text editor, dpkg says that I have no git installed. How to make dpkg's database to record that git is inatslled?

Thanks

Comment: As you're a reputation 26 user: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `checkinstall` – Track installation of local software, and produce a binary manageable with your package management software.

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

Go into your git source folder and start the installation again via

```
sudo checkinstall
```