# How to properly update / install / compile ibus on 14.04, dconf problems?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, compiling, ibus, dconf

I updated recently to phpstorm 9.5 and it says I should update ibus to 1.5.11 or newer (which at this point the current one).

Ok. I downloaded 1.5.11 from source and try to install it. I got some dependencies solved, but at one point I have a strange configuration error, that Package requirements (dconf >= 0.7.5) were not met.

after installing dconf-tools and other parts of the dconf package I still get this massage. Than I did  sudo apt-cache show dconf-tools and found in the output that libdconf0 (<< 0.7.3-2) is causing problems, as libdconf1 is 0.20.0-1 which seems to be newer.

Assuming that on 14.04 libconfd0 is not used anymore this information is obsolete for the compiling ibus.

How can I solve this?

**Edit 1:**

- installed dconf-tools, dconf-cli, dconf-editor as dconf package is not present in the packages.
- checked the /etc directory there is dconf related stuff there
- checked ibus/configure mechanism for dconf:

  ```
  if test x"$enable_dconf" = x"yes"; then
      # check dconf
      PKG_CHECK_MODULES(DCONF,
          [dconf >= 0.7.5],
      )
      PKG_CHECK_EXISTS([dconf >= 0.13.4],
          [AC_DEFINE(DCONF_0_13_4, TRUE, [dconf is 0.13.4 or later])],
          [])
      # check glib-compile-schemas
      GLIB_GSETTINGS
      enable_dconf="yes (enabled, use --disable-dconf to disable)"
  fi
  ```

**Edit 2:**

libdconf0 was misleading

Comment: as I could figure out, the libdconf0 assumption was misleading, checking the ibus configuration it simple uses PKG_CHECK_MODULES where I couldn't found any dconf.pc entries on my computer

Comment: `git` or `dconf`, that makes no difference. Simply use `checkinstall`, therefore your question is a duplicate of [Make dpkg to know compiled programs : git](http://askubuntu.com/questions/684909/make-dpkg-to-know-compiled-programs-git)

Comment: I'm not sure how it helps with dconf

Comment: still get No rule to make target `install' which means configure didn't run well of missing dconf which is not presence sudo apt-cache policy dconf

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add what you have done. E.g. where you have downloaded the dconf source.

Comment: sorry u r right, just didn't noticed that "edit" link below my original question even I was looking for it

Comment: And why is `libdconf0` installed? That package isn't available in Trusty. Why do you need `libdconf0`?

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove libdconf0; sudo apt-get install libdconf1`

Comment: @SándorBolla did you ever resolve this issue? also have the same problem, I just updated my webstorm to latest one.

Comment: @zulucoda yes, I could and it worked for 3 months till version 10 come out, which indeed has similar problems with ibus, but I switched over to android developement with android studio which is kinda' similar intellij product, we will see

Comment: @SándorBolla , Please write an answer instead of editing question. Make a look on this [about].

Comment: @Sneetsher I was misguided by A.B. requesting editing my original question to what I have done

Comment: Could you explain in detail how you went about building ibus 1.5.11? The source package https://github.com/ibus/ibus/releases/download/1.5.11/ibus-1.5.11.tar.gz has a README that points to "ibus-setup", which I only found as setup/ibus-setup.in (stupidly not executable), but I can't get that bash script to run (31: exec: @PYTHON@: not found).

Comment: https://github.com/ibus/ibus/wiki/Install has a COMPLETELY DIFFERENT set of instructions.  Most of the package dependencies are confusing (dbus-glib, dbus-python, notify-python, qt: none of these exist). Plus there are missing dependencies like autogen, gnome-common, and gtk-doc-tools. And then autogen.sh asks for 'gtk+-2.0' (and later 'gtk+-3.0'), which does not exist. Elsewhere in askubuntu, I find this is actually libgtk2.0-dev (libgtk-3-dev; note the inconsistent naming format). And finally 'dbus-1' for libdbus-1-dev.

Comment: [I updated directly from 16.04's version](https://serverfault.com/a/882330/432437).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For proper IntelliJ integration I had to compile iBus 1.5.11 from source.

To succeed on this I had to install `libdconf-dev` and `libnotify-dev`, which libs where not properly mentioned by to original ibus maintainer so I suggested him to add this information for a successful build process description on Debian based systems.

```
sudo apt-get install libdconf-dev libnotify-dev
```

Comment: I get `E: Unable to locate package libnofity-dev`. This answer doesn't help much as it. How did you compile from source? I found a tutorial here: https://serverfault.com/questions/735189/ibus-1-5-11-on-ubuntu but even tho, I don't really understand your solution.

Comment: the linked solution is for 15.04 not for 14.04, but `libnotify-dev` which was misspelled, I will edit the solution part

Comment: @SándorBolla , would you accept your own answer as it is the one that works for you. see https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Works, but what a pain to to have to do this.

Comment: Here are some alternatives to deal with iBus and IntelliJ if you don't need multiple keyboard support: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651898/resolving-ibus-issue-ibus-prior-to-1-5-11-may-cause-input-problems